# Settings for exporting collada (DAE) from Blender scene, specifically Human actors

Tags: collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Just wondering what specific options we need to have when exporting human characters designed in Blender to compatible with Gazebo actor animation.

Source code provided actor animation files (DAE) can be animated as shown by the original authors in [link text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7WEjAeztrc). Now I want to have my own body movements transferred in to the default Gazebo character. To begin with, I imported one of collada file (moonwalk.dae) and tried to export the selected character back in to Collada and use in Gazebo. That fails for some reason. Simple comparison with original file shows differences in library_controllers, pose matrix, mesh positions, etc. I tried with various Collada export options (Texture, Data, etc) and still fails to. Before debugging in to, I would like to know if somebody has been successful in exporting Blender files previously when this feature was working?

I am using Blender 2.70, 64 bit Windows 7.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6601/settings-for-exporting-collada-(dae)-from-blender-scene,-specifically-human-actors/) by [Kalana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/814/kalana/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Got it working! Actually missing of <library_controllers> was the major cause. Checked settings for getting it working are as follows. Could be helpful somebody else.

Export Data options: Selection Only, Include Children, Include Armatures

Texture options: Include UV Textures, Include Material Textures, Copy

Collada options: Triangulate, Use Object Instances, Transformation type: Matrix

---

Originally posted by [Kalana](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/814/kalana/) with karma: 36 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1